# Bootable USB for Windows 7 isn’t showing up on MacBook Pro 12,2

Tags: bootcamp, usb, startup, mojave, bootable-disk

I made a Windows 7 installation USB using Microsoft’s installation tool on my Windows PC. When I boot the Mac while holding <kbd>Option</kbd>. Only the Mac disk appears. The USB is NTFS. I checked if anything is wrong with the USB and nothing seems wrong. I’m not using Bootcamp because it only accepts Windows 10.

Is there any way to get it to appear? I don’t want to install Windows 7 in my Mac OSX disk using Virtual box.

Answer (score 1):

The Boot Camp Assistant will not accept Windows 7 because your Mac is a 2015 model. Starting in 2015, Apple eliminated including a legacy BIOS with the Mac firmware. Windows 7 can only BIOS boot and therefore can not be installed on your Mac. It does not matter how you create the flash drive or what method you use in an attempt to install.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware Apple took away the support for legacy booting in 2015+versions. Searching a bit, there are hacky ways to make it work (https://github.com/davidcie/VgaShim) but might not worth the hassle and you're better of running a VM or newer versions of Windows which have support for EFI, the type of firmware used by Apple (and most new computers) to boot partitions. (W7 doesn't support EFI)